# Order array of objects based on dependencies list?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I need to order an array of objects, composed by a name and a dependencies list (made out of names).

An example of this array could be:

```
[
  { name: 'a', requires: ['b', 'c'] },
  { name: 'b', requires: ['c'] },
  { name: 'c', requires: [] },
]
```

I'd like this array to be sorted so that the items which require a specific set of dependencies will be positioned after its required dependencies.
The array could actually contain more items, I'm okay if the sorting function throws an error in case of circular dependencies.

Example output:

```
[
  { name: 'c', requires: [] }, // first, no dependencies, and required by both the others
  { name: 'b', requires: ['c'] }, // second, because it needs `c` first
  { name: 'a', requires: ['b', 'c'] }, // last, because requires both the others
]
```

What's the most concise way to do it?

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: I don't know where to start actually @PeterB, my first attempt was with `Array.sort` but it doesn't fit the job.

Comment: @VigneshMurugan it's not a requirement, it's enough that the dependencies are satisfied

Comment: fyi This is not (just) a sorting problem, it is mostly a connected graph problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try following (changed test case to support more possible combinations)

```js
var arr = [
  { name: 'd', requires: ['a', 'c'] },
  { name: 'a', requires: ['b', 'c'] },
  { name: 'b', requires: ['c'] },
  { name: 'e', requires: ['d'] },
  { name: 'c', requires: [] },
];

var map = {}; // Creates key value pair of name and object
var result = []; // the result array
var visited = {}; // takes a note of the traversed dependency

arr.forEach(function(obj){ // build the map
  map[obj.name]  = obj;
});

arr.forEach(function(obj){ // Traverse array
  if(!visited[obj.name]) { // check for visited object
    sort_util(obj);
  }
});

// On visiting object, check for its dependencies and visit them recursively 
function sort_util(obj){
    visited[obj.name] = true;
    obj.requires.forEach(function(dep){
        if(!visited[dep]) {
           sort_util(map[dep]);
        } 
    });
    result.push(obj);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this solution works only (if at all) if the right oder is given. for an other given order, the dependencies are not respected.

Answer (score 1):

Update: thanks to Nina Scholz, I updated the code so that `sort` should work

This might do the job. 
The idea behind is, to user the `sort` and check if element `a` is in the requires of element `b`. If so, we can assume, that `a`should be before `b`.
But I´m not 100% sure, I just checked against your example and the example of @nikhilagw. I might have forgotten something. Please let me know if it worked!

For every element, I additionally inherit all dependencies.

```js
const list = [
{ name: 'b', requires: ['c'] },
{ name: 'e', requires: ['d'] },
{ name: 'd', requires: ['a', 'c'] },
{ name: 'c', requires: [] },  
{ name: 'a', requires: ['b', 'c'] }, 
];

// indexed by name
const mapped = list.reduce((mem, i) => {
  mem[i.name] = i;
  return mem;
}, {});

// inherit all dependencies for a given name
const inherited = i => {
  return mapped[i].requires.reduce((mem, i) => {
  return [ ...mem, i, ...inherited(i) ];
  }, []);
}

// order ... 
const ordered = list.sort((a, b) => {
  return !!~inherited(b.name).indexOf(a.name) ? -1 : 1;
})

console.log(ordered);
```

Comment: this solution works only (if at all) if the right oder is given. for an other given order, the dependencies are not respected.

Comment: but the items are not in the right order. why do you think it cannot work? can you explain?

Comment: actually i get `a d b e c`, which should be `c b a d e`, even if reversed, the result does not match. the problem with sort is, you check only two elements and their relation, bit it does not respect the previous neede elements, because of some elements points to an item and at the same time to the items predecessor.

Comment: You are right. I will fix it so that all dependencies will be inherited. That should fix that issue

Comment: @NinaScholz would you mind to check again? I still like the `sort` and a more functional approach.

Answer (score 0):

This proposal looks for previous elements and checks if the actual element has the wanted requirements sorted before.

If all requirements are found the object is spliced to the index.

```js
function order(array) {
    var i = 0,
        j,
        temp;

    while (i < array.length) {
        temp = array.slice(0, i);
        for (j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j].requires.every(n => temp.some(({ name }) => n === name))) {
                array.splice(i++, 0, array.splice(j, 1)[0]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}

var array = [{ name: 'd', requires: ['a', 'c'] }, { name: 'a', requires: ['b', 'c'] }, { name: 'b', requires: ['c'] }, { name: 'e', requires: ['d'] }, { name: 'c', requires: [] }];

console.log(order(array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

After several years I found this super short solution to the problem, a friend of mine shared it with me, I don't take credits.

```js
elements.sort((a, b) =>
  a.requires.includes(b.name) ? 1 : b.requires.includes(a.name) ? -1 : 0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data can be represented via graph. So you could use [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) for this problem.